# Openlayers requests to geoserver don't produce cached tiles

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache

I've created a grouped layer made from 4 MrSID rasters.
I have a Openlayers map with basic Google layer.
When I preview the grouped layer in geoserver , I see that tiles are being created in the GWC folder (tried both EPSG:4326 and EPSG:900919).

When I view the layer in my openlayers application (on same localhost machine) , no cached tiles are being created (I've cleared the browser cache to make sure the tiles are being generated from geoserver).

In my Openlayers I'm using GeoExt2 ... but still its regular WMS call.

Any idea why no tiles are being generated ?!

Comment: Tiles won't be created if you are hitting the WMS service, even if you have GWC installed and configured. To create the tiles, either seed the cache, or hit the GWC end point. And remember, if you want to consume the tiles, you need to use the GWC URL, not the WMS url.

Comment: If I seed the cache , calling the WMS will use the cached tiles or I must call GWC ?

Comment: You will have to call the GWC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Geoserver [Documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/index.html) mentions:

> GeoWebCache is a tiling server. It runs as a proxy between a map
>   client and map server, caching (storing) tiles as they are requested,
>   eliminating redundant request processing and thus saving large amounts
>   of processing time. GeoWebCache is integrated with GeoServer, though
>   it is also available as a standalone product for use with other map
>   servers.

GWC can act as a Wrapper to the WMS and you can use it in your app by using an url like: `http://example.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms` instead of `http://example.com/geoserver/wms`

If you want to use GWC tiles [directly from the WMS URL](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/using.html#direct-integration-with-geoserver-wms), you need to provide a `tiled=true` parameter  in the request.

The Tiles will be gnerated in two cases:

- Either you hit the GWC URL (directly or via the tiled=true parameter in the WMS request)
- or You [seed](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/seeding.html) the tile sets

To consume the tiles, you have to use GWC, via the URL or via the parameter in the WMS service

Comment: Thank you very much for this.
Its easy fix ... Just need to modify the url in the WMS call.
THX !!!